# Deleted Debian files (/usr)

Tags: linux, debian

I made a mount some weeks ago for many folders. (check pastebin)

Now i just wanted to delete them because i thought they are just a mounted folders.. it is not a problem if i delete them. But it is. I have deleted many important system files.

Is there any way to restore them? :/

It is a Debian linux system.

These are the deleted files: http://pastebin.com/M1cggFPB

Thanks !

update: there is no apt-get or etc
update2: I have copyed the usrbin back to its place but i have receive permission denied for all of them. (i logged in as root) Any idas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install the same version of the OS on another machine (or a VM), and copy the files you need over.  It's nice that you have a list.  :)

It's probably best not to restart the afflicted machine until  you're sure you've got everything.

Comment: I have copyed the usrbin back to its place but i have receive permission denied for all of them. (i logged in as root) Any idas?

Answer (score 0):

You could get a live cd/usb and reinstall them

In the live commandprompt:

First you have to know where your Linux partition is:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Then mount it: (ie /dev/sda1)

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

Now change your root folder to /mnt:

```
chroot /mnt
```

Now install the packages you want with apt-get: (ie gedit)

```
sudo apt-get install gedit
```

Have fun coding
-Charlie

Answer (score -1):

Permission problem:

There were no executable access.

Ruin: chmod +x *